# Consuming RabbitMQ queue with ElasticSearch in Java

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to create a specific *RabbitMQ* queue and have *ElasticSearch* as the consumer for the queue.

The most common way to create a queue in *Java* automatically right now is by using annotations from *Spring AMQP*.

But in my case, I need to create the queue explicitly and make call to the create queue method:

```
public  void createQueue() throws java.io.IOException { 
  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
  factory.setHost("localhost");
  Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
  Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
  channel.queueDeclare(TASK_QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
}
```

My understaning is that since the queue is created explicitly here, I would also have to create the *ElasticSearch* consumer for that queue also explicitly rather than through a `@Bean` annotations.

The only tutorial I found on creating *ElasticSearch* explicitly creates one like this:

```
//Create Client
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name","localtestsearch").build();
TransportClient transportClient=new TransportClient(settings);
transportClient = transportClient.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost",9300));
return(Client)transportClient;

//Create Index and set settings and mappings
CreateIndexRequestBuilder createIndexRequestBuilder=transportClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate(indexName);
createIndexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

//Add documents
IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder=transportClient().prepareIndex(indexName,documentType,documentId);

//build json object
XContentBuilder contentBuilder=jsonBuilder().startObject().prettyPrint();
contentBuilder.field("name","jai");
contentBuilder.stopObject();
indexRequestBuilder.setSource(contentBuilder);
IndexResponse response=indexRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
```

It's hard to see how `TransportClient` can be incorporated into my `createQueue()` method and consume the queue created.

Could anyone tell me what is missing in my source code?

Comment: Could you please state what you are trying to achieve exactly? What do you mean by consuming a RabbitMq queue with Elasticsearch?

Comment: @tmarwen So basically I am trying to establish a relationship where the messages received by the queue is passed to ElasticSearch.  So whenever a queue is created, there will be an ElasticSearch to consume any message that will come in.